# postgresql query optimization - 2GB database ends up being 50GB during query execution

Tags: sql, postgresql, lag, average, temporary

I have a database table called "Prices" which holds in itself data where there are different items with different prices and other properties.

My goal is to group this data by hour (many samples are being collected hourly). The summarized data should be inserted into table called "HourlyData".

The problem I am having is that my database which takes 2GB~ of space approximately at the moment ends up using over 40GB space during the query execution. That is bad news for me because I am using VPS and HDD capacity is limited and I end up having no space left on the device to finish the query execution.

I have included the SQLfiddle to ensure better code readability here:
**http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/38783/4**

There are two functions in the sqlfiddle paste, keep in mind that sqlfiddle doesn't support functions (as far as I know), so the code won't work without adjustments but for demonstration purposes it should be enough. Also the SCHEMA is built without correct ID syntax which should auto increment themselves and be primary keys of my tables - if that's somehow relevant.

Since I am a newbie to postgresql/SQL - to maintain this ton of code, I have chopped it into temporary tables instead of one big query with many subqueries inside. I am unsure if it's a bad practice usage of temporary tables or not but I haven't noticed a difference in CACHE with both ways.

**My question is, how could I go about this current execution more effectively?** 
I am using lots of AVG and LAG functions in the end of my second SQL function, I assume they are the ones to blame for cache building up but I haven't figured out a solution how could I do this piece by piece which would require less cache, since LAG function isn't usable with UPDATE command.

One of the solutions of course is to summarize the data more often in the future. The other solution I've came up with is to dump the database and download it from VPS and run the functions from local computer where HDD space isn't a problem. However I am hoping that this is more solvable with more experienced SQL programming - if its not then **is there anything I could do to optimize the current code anyway in terms of cache size?**

**Table code**

```
-- Table: "Prices"

-- DROP TABLE "Prices";

CREATE TABLE "Prices"
(
  data_id integer,
  level smallint,
  sell_price integer,
  buy_price integer,
  sell_count integer,
  buy_count integer, -- 
  name character varying(100),
  date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT ('now'::text)::timestamp(1) without time zone,
  "ID" serial NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "Prices_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);



-- Index: "Prices_ID_idx"


CREATE INDEX "Prices_ID_idx"
  ON "Prices"
  USING btree
  ("ID");

-- Index: "Prices_data_id_idx"

CREATE INDEX "Prices_data_id_idx"
  ON "Prices"
  USING btree
  (data_id);

-- Table: "HourlyData"


CREATE TABLE "HourlyData"
(
  data_id bigint,
  name character varying(100),
  date_time timestamp without time zone,
  hour integer,
  day integer,
  buy numeric(20,4),
  sell numeric(20,4),
  prev_buy numeric(20,4),
  prev_sell numeric(20,4),
  buy_count integer,
  sell_count integer,
  prev_buy_count integer,
  prev_sell_count integer,
  ab_change numeric(10,2),
  as_change numeric(10,2),
  abc_change numeric(10,2),
  asc_change numeric(10,2),
  "ID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"DailyData_ID_seq"'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT "DailyData_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);


-- Index: "DailyData_data_id_idx"


CREATE INDEX "DailyData_data_id_idx"
  ON "HourlyData"
  USING btree
  (data_id);


INSERT INTO Prices
    ("data_id", "level", "sell_price", "buy_price", "sell_count", "buy_count", "name", "date")
VALUES
    (28262, 80, 18899, 15000, 53, 66, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 01:38:07'),
    (28262, 80, 18899, 15000, 53, 66, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 01:44:31'),
    (28262, 80, 18987, 15000, 46, 65, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 01:30:22'),
    (28262, 80, 18987, 16000, 49, 65, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 01:00:19'),
    (28265, 80, 18987, 16000, 48, 64, 'random_itema', '2013-12-16 01:30:20'),
    (28265, 80, 18987, 16000, 48, 64, 'random_itema', '2013-12-16 01:00:21'),
    (28265, 80, 17087, 16000, 49, 63, 'random_itema', '2013-12-16 01:30:22'),
    (28262, 80, 18980, 5028, 48, 62, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 10:00:28'),
    (28262, 80, 18975, 5528, 50, 60, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 10:30:30'),
    (28262, 80, 18975, 5228, 51, 59, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 10:00:27'),
    (28262, 80, 18975, 5500, 52, 59, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 10:30:21'),
    (28262, 80, 18975, 5600, 53, 59, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 10:00:23'),
    (28262, 80, 18979, 5700, 50, 58, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 10:30:28'),
    (28262, 80, 18977, 5028, 51, 56, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 10:00:23'),
    (28264, 80, 18978, 5028, 51, 54, 'random_itemaw', '2013-12-16 10:30:25'),
    (28264, 80, 18979, 5628, 50, 54, 'random_itemaw', '2013-12-16 10:00:28'),
    (28264, 80, 18979, 5028, 52, 64, 'random_itemaw', '2013-12-16 10:30:26'),
    (28264, 80, 18979, 15028, 52, 64, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 11:00:25'),
    (28264, 80, 17977, 15028, 56, 63, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 11:30:24'),
    (28264, 80, 17977, 15029, 58, 62, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 11:00:30'),
    (28262, 80, 17977, 15027, 58, 62, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 11:30:22'),
    (28262, 80, 16000, 15022, 59, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 11:00:26'),
    (28262, 80, 17979, 15021, 56, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 11:30:26'),
    (28262, 80, 17969, 15023, 58, 44, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 11:00:31'),
    (28262, 80, 18987, 15027, 48, 44, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 12:30:33'),
    (28262, 80, 20819, 15027, 40, 43, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 12:00:32'),
    (28262, 80, 21810, 15034, 37, 48, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 12:30:24'),
    (28262, 80, 21810, 15037, 39, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 22:00:18'),
    (28262, 80, 21810, 15038, 39, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 22:30:25'),
    (28262, 80, 21810, 15038, 39, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 22:00:25'),
    (28262, 80, 21710, 15039, 40, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 22:30:24'),
    (28262, 80, 21709, 15040, 41, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 22:00:24'),
    (28262, 80, 21709, 15040, 41, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 22:30:22'),
    (28262, 80, 21709, 15040, 41, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 23:00:24'),
    (28262, 80, 21709, 15041, 41, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-16 23:30:27'),
    (28266, 80, 21708, 15042, 42, 50, 'random_item1', '2013-12-17 05:00:26'),
    (28266, 80, 20000, 15041, 43, 49, 'random_item1', '2013-12-17 05:30:21'),
    (28266, 80, 20000, 15097, 43, 52, 'random_item1', '2013-12-17 05:00:28'),
    (28262, 80, 20000, 15097, 43, 52, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:30:28'),
    (28262, 80, 20000, 15097, 43, 52, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:00:31'),
    (28262, 80, 20000, 15097, 44, 51, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:30:34'),
    (28262, 80, 19997, 15097, 44, 47, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:00:20'),
    (28262, 80, 19997, 15098, 44, 50, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:30:26'),
    (28262, 80, 19997, 15098, 44, 50, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:00:24'),
    (28262, 80, 19997, 15098, 44, 49, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:35:44'),
    (28262, 80, 19996, 15098, 45, 48, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:00:22'),
    (28262, 80, 19996, 15097, 46, 47, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:30:24'),
    (28262, 80, 19996, 15097, 46, 47, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:00:29'),
    (28262, 80, 19996, 15097, 46, 47, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:30:24'),
    (28262, 80, 19996, 15041, 47, 46, 'random_item', '2013-12-17 05:00:25')
;
```

**Functions**

```
-- Function: percentageincrease(numeric, numeric)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION percentageincrease(lugeja numeric, nimetaja numeric)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF Nimetaja IS NULL or Nimetaja = 0 
        THEN RETURN 0;
    ELSE
        RETURN ROUND((Lugeja - Nimetaja) / Nimetaja * 100, 2);
    END IF;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Function: process_hourly_data()

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_hourly_data()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$  

    CREATE TEMP TABLE "TEMP_summarize1" AS
    SELECT
                prices.data_id AS data_id,
                prices.name AS name,

                date_part('hour', prices.date) AS hour,
                date_part('day', prices.date) AS day,
                prices.date AS date_var,
                prices.buy_price,
                prices.sell_price,                            
                prices.sell_count,
                prices.buy_count

    FROM "Prices" as prices;

    CREATE TEMP TABLE "TEMP_summarize2"
    (
        item_name character varying(100),
        data_id bigint, 
        hour integer,
        day integer,
        date_var timestamp without time zone,
        avgbuy smallint,
        avgsell smallint,
        avgsellCount smallint,
        avgbuyCount smallint
    );


    PREPARE TEMP2 AS
    INSERT INTO "TEMP_summarize2"
    SELECT
       MAX(whatever.name) as item_name,
       whatever.data_id,
       prices.hour,
       MAX(prices.day) as day,
       MAX(prices.date_var) as date_var,
       AVG(prices.buy_price) AS avgbuy,
       AVG(prices.sell_price) AS avgsell,
       AVG(prices.sell_count) AS avgsellCount,
       AVG(prices.buy_count) AS avgbuyCount 
    FROM "TEMP_summarize1" AS prices, (SELECT data_id, name FROM "TEMP_summarize1" as whatever) AS whatever
        WHERE whatever.data_id = prices.data_id AND whatever.name = prices.name
        GROUP BY hour, whatever.data_id;

    PREPARE TEMP3 AS
    INSERT INTO "HourlyData"
    SELECT 
        data_id,
        item_name,
        date_var,
        hour,
        day,
        avgbuy,
        avgsell,
        LAG(avgbuy, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY data_id) AS last_avgbuy,
        LAG(avgsell, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY data_id) AS last_avgsell,
        avgsellCount,
        avgbuyCount,
        LAG(avgsellCount, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY data_id) AS last_avgsellCount,
        LAG(avgbuyCount, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY data_id) AS last_avgbuyCount,
        percentageincrease(LAG(avgbuy, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY data_id), avgbuy),
        percentageincrease(LAG(avgsell, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY data_id), avgsell),
        percentageincrease(LAG(avgsellCount, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY data_id), avgsellCount),
        percentageincrease(LAG(avgbuyCount, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY data_id), avgbuyCount)

    FROM "TEMP_summarize2"
    ORDER BY data_id, hour; 
    EXECUTE TEMP2;
    EXECUTE TEMP3;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: What's the date range here?  You're aware that you potentially have duplicate `day`/`hourly` tuples if the data runs more than one month, right?  Part of your problem is likely due to use of explicit temp tables - RDBMSs are usually pretty good about only building exactly what is needed for a query, so combining it into one query _might_ help.  40GB seems overly large, though.  I assume you have appropriate indices?  Also, without `ORDER BY` being specified _inside_ the windowing function, I'm concerned that `LAG()` may give "undefined" results (dependent on optimizer whim).

Comment: Your tables don't have any PK or FK's in them. Also, the default value for the timstamp looks wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try something like the following:

```
WITH Date_Range as (SELECT calendarDate, timeOfDay, 
                           calendarDate + timeOfDay as rangeStart,
                           (calendarDate + timeOfDay) + INTERVAL '1 hour' as rangeEnd
                    FROM Calendar
                    CROSS JOIN TimeOfDay
                    WHERE calendarDate >= CAST('2013-12-16' as DATE)
                          AND calendarDate < CAST('2013-12-18' as DATE))

INSERT INTO HourlyData

SELECT data_id,
       randomName,
       latestPriceChangeAt,
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM timeOfDay) as hourOfDay,
       EXTRACT(DAY FROM calendarDate) as dayOfMonth,
       averageBuyPrice,
       averageSellPrice,
       previousAverageBuyPrice,
       previousAverageSellPrice,
       averageBuyCount,
       averageSellCount,
       previousAverageBuyCount,
       previousAverageSellCount,
       -- put the calls to your function here instead of these operations
       averageBuyPrice - previousAverageBuyPrice,
       averageSellPrice - previousAverageSellPrice,
       averageBuyCount - previousAverageBuyCount,
       averageSellCount - previousAverageSellCount


FROM (SELECT data_id, calendarDate, timeOfDay,
             MAX(date) as latestPriceChangeAt,
             MAX(name) as randomName,
             AVG(sell_price) as averageSellPrice,
             AVG(sell_count) as averageSellCount,
             AVG(buy_price) as averageBuyPrice,
             AVG(buy_count) as averageBuyCount,
             LAG(AVG(buy_price)) OVER(PARTITION BY data_id ORDER BY calendarDate, timeOfDay) as previousAverageBuyPrice,
             LAG(AVG(sell_price)) OVER(PARTITION BY data_id ORDER BY calendarDate, timeOfDay) as previousAverageSellPrice,
             LAG(AVG(buy_count)) OVER(PARTITION BY data_id ORDER BY calendarDate, timeOfDay) as previousAverageBuyCount,
             LAG(AVG(sell_count)) OVER(PARTITION BY data_id ORDER BY calendarDate, timeOfDay) as previousAverageSellCount
      FROM Date_Range
      JOIN Prices
        ON Prices.date >= Date_Range.rangeStart
           AND prices.date < Date_Range.rangeEnd
      GROUP BY data_id, calendarDate, timeOfDay) data;
```

(Using your initial [SQL Fiddle as the base](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e5979/20))

Note that I've changed the rollup to also be by *day*, not just hour, as otherwise your result columns are slightly odd.  This is trivial to change if you wanted to group all days together, though.  I'm also assuming you have a calendar/time of day table, which are ridiculously handy tools to have for analysis purposes.  If you don't have one/can't create one, they can be created pretty easily with recursive CTEs.  All query work assumes you also have appropriate indices - otherwise, your system will likely create some temporary ones...

I personally think your biggest problem is attempting to "optimize" your query with temp tables, for what should be a simple aggregate query.  What you're doing *does* work in some situations (and is occasionally necessary), but the version you were using wasn't helping any - there was a self-join in the `prices` table, which was likely a huge offender.

Comment: I have accepted this answer because it offers exactly the kind of advice I was looking for. 

The time-period table is really useful. I did not use one myself and now I have learned that it's actually a common practice in given situations. Never wouldn't had thought about it myself.

Also my main problem is solved where the query is no longer having problems with executing on my VPS. Your solution has also shown me how to better organize my code.

In conclusion, this answer optimizes the code, simplifies it and even makes it work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same kind of issue. The issue might be caused because of `UPDATE` statements. Are you using `COMMIT` to commit your changes to the database? If you use `COMMIT` for each `UPDATE` then the cache size will definitely grow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a internal behavior of windows functions. There are two possibilities:

- Test for decreasing `work_mem` (it can be decreased per query) - it can decrease the speed of your query, but it can decrease memory consumption

  ```
  SET work_mem = '1MB'
  ```
- Use a stored procedure with explicit iteration over a cursor. Lot of `window' function can be emulated (and it is a typical solution in pre-windows function era). It should have a significantly smaller memory footprint:

  ```
  DO $$
  DECLARE 
    t_1 foo;
    t_2 foo;
    t_3 foo;
    r foo;
  FOR r IN SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY some_col
  LOOP
    /* move history records */
    t_3 := t_2;
    t_2 := t_1;
    t_1 := r;

    -- now in t_1, t_2, and t_3 are presorted records
    -- do something there
  END LOOP;
  $$;
  ```